# Difficulty in compiling an old Python file in a new Interpreter

Tags: python, printing

Print statement had no parenthesis in Python 2. I am trying to run a file having print statements with no parentheses in an advanced version of python, but the Interpreter throws an error regarding the absence of parenthesis. How can I deal with this problem? Would I need to put a parenthesis with every occurrence of print? Or is there a workaround?

I tried to find an answer on Google but couldn't find a workable solution.

Comment: Python has an automated solution for updating version 2 code to version 3. [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html). Otherwise, yes you will have to put parenthesis for every occurrence of print.

Comment: BTW Python is not a compiled language.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes. No. Maybe. Python is compiled to byte code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a specific migration tool that can help you convert Python 2 code to Python 3 code. This tool is called 2to3, and the documentation for it can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html).

Basically, all you need to do is run `2to3 -w your_file.py`. This command will make the necessary modifications to your script and automatically create a backup file.

You can also provide a [predefined fixer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#to3-fixers) to ensure that print statements are fixed. This can be achieved with the following command: `2to3 -W -f print your_file.py`.

Just a minor correction: Python is an interpreted language, so it doesn't have a compiler but an interpreter.

Comment: To cite the documentation of [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) in Pythons Standard Library: "These functions compile Python source files in a directory tree.". You are correct in that it does not compile in machine language but in bytecode.

Comment: @mferraz  Thanks, it works. I searched out the idea shared by you and found a web resource that can do it (https://python2to3.com/)